# Python Script to Show it's Still Receiving Data

Tags: python, server, anaconda, command-prompt

I have a script running 24 hrs a day connected to a server that is giving me data roughly once a second. This leaves a command prompt open and when I need to act on that data, I have some printouts to keep me updated on what state it's in. Unless it needs to make changes, I have no way of knowing that it's still receiving data. I'm not interested in cluttering up the space with 'print every x loops'.

When I update anaconda through command prompt, it displays a spinning line in place while it retrieves data. How can I mimic something like this?

EDIT: I have Yaspin working but there's odd visual with windows cmd.

I made a very basic script to show the visual. You can see the 'line', and it is spinning, but what are the other characters?
[image]

Comment: You might take a look at https://github.com/pavdmyt/yaspin, which creates a "spinner" in a console.

Comment: The `rich` console package also provides spinners.  Alternatively, you could use a `tqdm` progress bar you update whenever new data comes through.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have added yaspin to my code, but my script runs in a CMD instance and it adds some extra characters 'visually' after the spinner. Is there any way to clean that up? I can't find any documentation on this occurring.

Comment: Beats me.  You have the source code.  What do you mean by "extra characters"?

Comment: @TimRoberts I edited the question so you can see. I tested this on 2 computers with the same result.

Comment: Your code runs correctly on MacOS terminal. Look like  your terminal does not understand ANSI control seqiences.

Comment: RIght, it's an Anaconda issue.  If you ran it in a terminal, it would be OK.  If you really need to run in Anaconda, you'll need a different module.